# Access facebook public profile newsfeed without using access token

Tags: facebook, web-services, facebook-graph-api

Can we access news-feed, posts and other public information of public celebrity profiles (some of them can we verified too)
[like1](https://www.facebook.com/BeingSalmanKhan) and [like2](https://www.facebook.com/Rajesh-Kalra-874777125940379)

without having access token using spring social or other better way.

Comment: No. All API calls require an access token.

Comment: @WizKid if we want to get the public profiles timeline feed , is there any menthod available using which we don't require any user approval or signin for our app??

Comment: According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/feed : No.

Comment: I found one way like below :  https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_PAGE_ID/posts?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

@source http://johndoesdesign.com/blog/2011/php/adding-a-facebook-news-status-feed-to-a-website/

Answer (score 0):

You can use an App Token or User Token, for example: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=BeingSalmanKhan%2Ffeed&version=v2.4

It is not possible without a Token.